# Не выводится бд sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Пытаюсь освоиться в sqlite, но вот не могу вывести свою переменную. В чем может быть проблема? Код:

```
import sqlite3
import random
chars = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
def insert_payid():
    payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(15))  # генерируем сам код, который состоит из 15 символов
    gtavgen_tokens = sqlite3.connect('gtavgen_tokens')
    sql = gtavgen_tokens.cursor()
    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gtavtokens (gtavtokens TEXT)""")
    gtavgen_tokens.commit()
    payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(15)) #отладка
    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO gtavtokens VALUES (?)", (payid))
    gtavgen_tokens.commit()
    #gtavgen_tokens.close()
    print("Успешно!")
    for value in sql.execute("SELECT * FROM gtavtokens"):
        print(value)
    gtavgen_tokens.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вам необходимо вызвать саму функцию `insert_payid()`, сделать это можно дописав в конце вашего кода `insert_payid()`

> Также при запуске вашего кода происходит ошибка `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 15 supplied.`, в которой говорится, что вы создали одну ячейку а пытаетесь вставить 15 значений в несуществующие ячейки `( примерно так )`

> Чтобы обойти ошибку `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 15 supplied.`, вам необходимо на `11 строке` после `payid` дописать запятую в итоге должно получится так: `(payid,))`  #<---- сюда поставил запятую

> Полностью весь рабочий код:

```
import sqlite3
import random
chars = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
def insert_payid():
    payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(15))  # генерируем сам код, который состоит из 15 символов
    gtavgen_tokens = sqlite3.connect('gtavgen_tokens')
    sql = gtavgen_tokens.cursor()
    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gtavtokens (gtavtokens TEXT)""")
    gtavgen_tokens.commit()
    payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(15)) #отладка
    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO gtavtokens VALUES (?)", (payid,))
    gtavgen_tokens.commit()
    #gtavgen_tokens.close()
    print("Успешно!")
    for value in sql.execute("SELECT * FROM gtavtokens"):
        print(value)
    gtavgen_tokens.close()

insert_payid()
```